Perron Frobinius Theorem proof using Collatz-Wielandt Formula

$\hspace{3.5cm}$ Perron-Frobenius Theorem
If $\mathbf{A}_{n \times n} \geq \mathbf{0}$ is irreducible,then each of the following is true.

$\bullet$ $\quad$ $r = \rho(\mathbf{A}) \in \sigma(\mathbf{A}) \quad \text{and} \quad r > 0$. $\hspace{7.5cm}(8.3.6)$

$\bullet$ $\quad$ $alg \, mult_{\mathbf{A}} (r) = 1$. $\hspace{10.2cm}(8.3.7)$

$\bullet$ $\quad$ $\text{There exists an eigenvector} \,\, \mathbf{x} > 0 \,\, \text{such that} \,\, \mathbf{Ax} = r\mathbf{x}$. $\hspace{3.2cm}(8.3.8)$

$\bullet$ $\quad$ $\text{The unique vector defined by}$
$$\mathbf{Ap} = r\mathbf{p}, \quad \mathbf{p} > 0, \quad \text{and} \quad \|\mathbf{p}\|_1 = 1, \tag{8.3.9}$$
$\qquad$ is called the Perron vector. There are no nonnegative eigenvectors for $\mathbf{A}$ except for $\qquad$ positive  multiples of $\mathbf{p}$, regardless of the eigenvalue.

$\bullet$ $\quad$ $\text{The Collatz-Wielandt formula} \quad r = \max_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{N}} f(\mathbf{x})$,
\begin{equation*}
    \text{where} \quad f(\mathbf{x}) = \, \substack{\Large {\min} \\ 1 \leq i \leq n \\ x_i \neq 0} \frac{[\mathbf{Ax}]_i}{x_i} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{N} = \{\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0} \text{ with } \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}\}
\end{equation*}
$\qquad$ was established in $(8.3.3)$ for all nonnegative matrices, but it is included here for the $\qquad$ sake of completeness.


$\hspace{5cm}$ Collatz-Wielandt Formula
The Perron root of $\mathbf{A}_{n \times n} \gt \mathbf{0}$ is given by $r = \max_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{N}} f(\mathbf{x})$, where
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \substack{\Large{\min} \\ 1 \leq i \leq n, \\ x_i \neq 0} \frac{[\mathbf{Ax}]_i}{x_i}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad \mathcal{N} = \{\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{0} \quad \text{with} \quad \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}\}.
$$

As per Wikipedia, it's been stated that Wielandt was able to prove Perron-Frobenius Theorem using Collatz-Wielandt Formula:

A common thread in many proofs is the Brouwer fixed point theorem. Another popular method is that of Wielandt (1950). He used the Collatz–Wielandt formula described above to extend and clarify Frobenius's work.$^{[29]}$ Another proof is based on the spectral theory$^{[30]}$ from which part of the arguments are borrowed.

Could anyone share the detailed proof and its proof of (existence and properties) in the Wielandt approach or the way he proved.
Or Another way to state Question given a Matrix A and quantity a such that a=min of (Ax)i/(x)i,then s is max of quantity a over vector space x ,then show that not only s is a eigenvalue of A but also the maximum eigenvalue of A

That is the ploblem everyone paper Perron, Frobenius and weidlant all their papers are in german,and i dont understand german.I tried to translate papers but i didnt seem to work @BrauerSuzuki

Who has deleted my comment?


(Source: Berstel, Perrin, and Reutenauer, Codes and Automata, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications 129, Cambridge University Press, 2010, pp. 30-31.)
I think this answers your first question.

Please do not post images containing text in your answer. Rather cite the result, provide at least a sketch of an argument or do both.

Atleast i gave an answer when no one did,sender is my friend.@DeanMiller

Is it that difficult to give a citation?
